# Abstract iterator in Do

Tags: matrix, tensors, iterators

I'm trying to write a module. Its input is a matrix (tensor), the module should return new tensor with increased rank with 1. The new tensor is defined as
$$
O \Rightarrow N_{\alpha \beta \ldots \sigma}^{\gamma \delta \ldots}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\sigma}} O_{\alpha \beta \ldots}^{\gamma \delta \ldots}
$$ 
where $O$ is input ("old tensor") and $N$ is new tensor returned by module. Since the module should work for tensor of general rank (general number of indices), i try to obtain rank of input tensor, generate list of indices representing elements and set them in *Do* loop (see commentary in code). The problem is in setting values (element by element) in *Do* loop:

```
PartialDerivative[tensor_] := 
 Module[{tens = tensor, oldorder, neworder, dlist, newtensor, \[Mu], 
   i, doparams, \[Alpha], l, d, r},
(*coordinates, derivate with respect to them*)
  r = {t, x, y, z};
(*dimension*)
  d = 4;
(*rank of input tensor*)
  oldorder = ArrayDepth[tens];
(*rank of new tensor*)
  neworder = oldorder + 1;
(*create list {d,d,...d} for creation of new tensor*)
  dlist = Table[d, {i, neworder}];
(*create new dummy tensor with correct size *)
  newtensor = SparseArray[{}, dlist];
(*now I try to create iterator list for last Do loop*)
  l = {};
(*
lets join all individual iterators, each is type {\[Mu][i], 1, d}
e.g. the first one is {\[Mu][1], 1, d}
and join them into one list
*)
  Do[l = Join[l, {{\[Mu][i], 1, d}}], {i, 1, oldorder}];
(*join the last iterator - the derivative index*)
  l = Join[l, {{\[Alpha], 1, d}}];
(*now create Sequence from the list*)
  doparams = Delete[l, 0];
(*now assign elements of the new tensor from the old tensor - Error line*)
  Do[newtensor[[Delete[Array[\[Mu], d], 0], \[Alpha]]] = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \
\(r[\([\[Alpha]]\)]\)]\(tens[\([Delete[Array[\[Mu], d], 0]]\)]\)\), 
   doparams];
  Return[newtensor];
  ]
(*calling example - should return identity matrix 4x4*)
PartialDerivative[{t, x, y, z}]
```

Everything seems to work fine until the the *Error line* (see code, the line above returning new tensor), where I get error

*Argument doparams$22092 at position 2 does not have the correct form
for an iterator.*

Do you know where is mistake? Or is there another or simpler way to write the function?

Thank you for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was somehow in the variables $\mu[i]$, so instead i used variables automatically generated variables

```
Unique["\[Mu]"]
```

which are unique and are numbered in way $\mu 12, \mu 35, ...$, so there is no problem with brackets. Also it was needed to call evaluate inside *Do*.

```
PartialDerivative[tensor_] := Module[
  {tens = tensor, oldorder, neworder, dlist, newtensor, \[Mu], i, 
   doparams, \[Alpha], l, l2, d, r, variables},

  r = {t, x, y, z};
  d = 4;
  oldorder = ArrayDepth[tens];
  neworder = oldorder + 1;
  dlist = Table[d, {i, neworder}];
  variables = Table[Unique["\[Mu]"], {oldorder}];
  newtensor = SparseArray[{}, dlist];
  l = Table[{variables[[j]], 1, d}, {j, 1, oldorder}];
  l2 = Join[l, {{\[Alpha], 1, d}}];
  Print[l];
  Print[l2];
  doparams = Delete[l2, 0];
  Print[doparams];

  Do[newtensor[[Delete[variables, 0], \[Alpha]]] = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r[\([\)\(\[Alpha]\)\(]\)]\)]\(tens[\
\([Delete[variables, 0]]\)]\)\), doparams // Evaluate];
  Return[newtensor];
  ]
PartialDerivative[{t, x, y, z}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `r` and `d` be determined from the input, not hard-coded?